# Coefficient of sum of homogeneous polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $k$ be a field. Suppose $m(x)\in k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ is a monomial of degree $d$, and there is a decomposition
$$
m(x)=\sum_if_i(x)g_i(x)
$$
where $f_i(x)$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degrees (with $\deg f_i(x)<\deg m(x)$). Is it possibly to say $g_i(x)$'s are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the answer is no. For example, $x = x(x+1) - x(x)$, but $x+1$ is not homogenous.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes that's a good point. I've editted it so that this cannot happen.

Comment: It is still not true. For example, $x^2 = x(x^2+x) - x(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. For example, $x^2 = x(x^2+x) - x(x^2)$. Or $x^2 = x(x+1) - x(1)$.